# Amazon AWS ItemSearch returns no description

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Ok, I've started learning Amazon's AWS API, and I'm really confused whether or not I could get item description using ItemSearch - tried so many different ResponseGroup options now, no luck. Here's the [sample code](https://github.com/t3chnoboy/amazon-product-api) I've been using to learn the api(tried to get movie description):

```
client.itemSearch({
  director: 'Quentin Tarantino',
  actor: 'Samuel L. Jackson',
  searchIndex: 'DVD',
  audienceRating: 'R',
  responseGroup: 'ItemAttributes,Offers,Images'
}).then(function(results){
  console.log(results);
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

I want to know what request parameters to apply to get movie description and where it's hidden in response(eg I get title using `movie.ItemAttributes[0].Title[0]`).
Thanks in advance.